# error during angular6 installation on ubundu 18.04

Tags: angular6, failed-installation

Error during angular6 installation using the command 
**npm install -g @angular/cli**

following error showing
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your operating system or architecture: fsevents@1.2.4
npm ERR! Linux 4.15.0-36-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "@angular/cli"
npm ERR! node v8.10.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.5.2
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! syscall access

npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib'
npm ERR!  { Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib'
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'access',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/shahid/npm-debug.log

Answer (score 0):

Run the following command as told

```
sudo npm install -g @angular/cli
```

angular needs to be installed as root user.

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu while you are install any package with `-g` , then Ubuntu must need's the **root** level permission.

For that you can assign permission via `sudo` command.

Use this command.

```
sudo npm install -g @angular/cli
```

Then it will ask for password and enter your system password. :)